# Firebase firestore retrieve documents that are not in a document array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a search bar that retrieve documents from firestore that matches a string value. What I want is not retrieve documents that I have retrieved before, which are stored in a `Set<documents>`.

Is that possible in Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`not-in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any), which allows you to specify values not to retrieve. If you want to do this based on the document ID, you can specify `FieldPath.documentId()` for the field name.

Comment: Thank you! I was just reading about that. In documentation says that can be done with at most 10 OR, and for other cases, create separate querys. Do you know how to do that? Add more than 10 documents to the clause

Comment: As the documentation says: you can specify at most 10 values to exclude. If you need more than 10, you'll have to find another solution - as that's the limit.